# Store SHA1 hash digest of a FreeRADIUS user password in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04, sha, freeradius

I have a system with a centralized user database where usernames and passwords are stored for different application.
The database is created in PostgreSQL. FreeRDAIUS gets access to the users and passwords via OpenLDAP which uses PostgreSQL as a backend system. The passwords are supposed to be stored in their hash formats.
I have tested FreeRADIUS with SHA1 passwords stored in the database and users are successfully authenticated. I stored the digest with {SHA} prepnded to it and it work perfectly. This hash, however, needs to be in base64 with "=" as the a padding character. I generated the base64 hash digest using ldap utility slappasswd.

Since in reality, I am supposed to insert users in the database using a C function and the available cryptographic libs such as OpenSSL only offer function for hex hash, I thought the best way is to know how to tell FreeRDAIUS that the digest stored in the database is NOT base64 but HEX.

Does anyone know how I can do this? It seems that if I simply put {SHA} before the hashed value, it only works for base64 with FreeRADIUS. I would also like to know if FreeRADIUS supports other hash algorithms such as SHA256.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
PostgreSQL: 9.1
FreeRADIUS: 2.1.10

Answer (score 0):

No currently released versions support any of the SHA-2 hash algorithms.

The rlm_pap module in FreeRADIUS 2.1.10 should automatically 'normify' the 'known good' password, that is convert the hexits to binary, and assign it to the correct `control:` attribute. This works the same way for hexits as it does base64.

*Update:*
https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/commit/0bd0f7453adb2c331a9c1127eda9c9a9fe203b2d

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't seem that it accepts the SHA1 hex digest. As I said it works perfectly with BASE64 and the user authentication with radtest is successful. Do I need to modify a parameter in the RADIUS server?

Comment: No, there are no useful parameters in rlm_pap for that version of the server other than `auto_header` which should be `yes`, and `encryption_scheme` which should be `auto`. Ensure that you're not prepending '0x' to the hex string, that the hex string has not been truncated, that there's no white space, and that your hex string consists of exactly 40 hexits.